# escoger valor random de un array

Tags: javascript

tengo un array con 807 valores y deseo poder escoger uno de ellos al azar el problema es que solo puedo escoger 10 con el método de random(), de que otra manera lo puedo hacer?

```js
let arrayNumeros = []

function numbers1() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 807; i++) {
        arrayNumeros.push(i)
    }
}
numbers1()
```

Comment: Tu código no indica dónde estás eligiendo al azar. Procura plantear siempre ejemplos verificables en tus preguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un número random entre 0 y 806 (los indices de los arrays comienzan con 0 y no con  1), a partir de un número (pseudo) random entre 0 y 1 pero **sin incluír** el 1 [0,1) que nos provee `Math.random()`.

Entonces, lo mejor que se puede hacer es multiplicar ambos números, ya que como el random es menor que 1, el resultado será siempre menor a 806 e igual o mayor a 0. Ahora bien, el 806 nunca saldrá porque nunca se dará el caso 1*806, entonces al límite superior hay que sumarle uno. Dicho esto, la forma sería entonces:

`Math.random()*807`

como eso da un número decimal, se le puede hacer `Math.floor` que nos dá el menor número entero, lo que nos permite incluír el 0 entre los resultados, además de interpretar el 806.999999 como 806, y no como 807. Entonces, si quieres encontrar un número entre 0 y 806 (807 elementos) la forma sería:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*807)
```

Answer (score 7):

Puedes generar un numero aleatorio con un mínimo de 0 y máximo el tamaño de tu array para nunca estar fuera de rango. Una vez tengamos el numero random, lo utilizaremos como indice para acceder al array con todos los valores.

```
var numbers = []

function llenar() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 807; i++) {
        numbers.push(i)
    }
}
llenar()

function random() {
 let number = Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length);
 return number
}

let position = random()
let number = numbers[position]
console.log(`Numero random: ${position}, elemento correspondiente: ${number}`)
```

> Recuerda que cuando trabajamos con un array, los indices comienzan en 0

Comment: *algo* -1  - 0  +1  es igual a *algo*, para encontrar un número entre 0 y numbers.length -1 la  función debería ser `Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length );`

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, he actualizado la respuesta para una sintaxis más limpia. Gracias por la acotación !